# Understanding the beginning, while, sum, and end of an algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming

My problem is as follows:

\1brace **procedure** *sum* (n: positive number)
*sum*:=0

**while** i < 10

**begin**

*sum* :=*sum* + i

**end**

output(*sum*) \rbrace

Then, I have the following choices to select from as a possible correct statement (or statements):

A. If i is initialized to the value 1 in the beginning of the algorithm, the algorithm works and outputs 1 + 2 + ... + 9.

B. If i is initialized to the value 1 in the beginning of the algorithm, the algorithm works and outputs 1 + 2 + ... + 10.

C. If i is initialized to the value 1 in the beginning of the algorithm, the algorithm is still not finite since it gets stuck in an infinite while loop.

D. This algorithm does not seem to use the input n.

E. If i is initialized to the value 1 in the beginning of the algorithm, the algorithm works and outputs 1.

F. This algorithm lacks preciseness since the value of i is not initialized.

I have no experience with code and its connection with algorithms, and so this entire problem confuses me. To be specific, I would appreciate help interpreting what the different parts of the algorithm mean. For example, I don't know what \1brace or \rbrace stand for. From what I interpret (although I don't know if this is close to being correct) it looks like I would start with some value, say 0, and add 1 = 1. Then I would take 1 and add 1 = 2. Then take 2 and add 1 = 3...

I thought that the solution might be C, D, and F just based on observation. (I didn't see how it could be finite since it says + i, I didn't see n used, and I didn't see a starting value identified.) I did get this marked as the correct answer, but I still feel that I don't have a solid understanding of the basic components involved. Any insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Better suited to a programming site, I think, though I am sure there are many here who will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Gerry - this is my first post on this site and so I was hoping I was on the right track with how I set up the question. I added a programming tag. That was a good idea.